# p:steps example not functioning

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying use the STEPS component - Primefaces. But in the documentation the tutorial is very poor.

Can someone write an example using steps with property rendered or something like that, how Can I show and hide a panel using STEPS component.

I tried like this but does not work

My xhtml

```
<p:steps id="testSteps">
            <p:menuitem value="Personal" update="testSteps" actionListener="#{BeanTest.shown2()}"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Seat Selection" update="testSteps"/>
        </p:steps>

        <form id="formShowField1" >
            <p:panel rendered="#{BeanTest.showfield1}">
                     <p:outputLabel value="FORM 1"/>
            </p:panel>
        </form>

        <form id="formShowField2">
            <p:panel rendered="#{BeanTest.showfield2}">
                <p:outputLabel value="FORM 2" />
            </p:panel>
        </form>
```

My bean

```
public void shown1(){
    showfield1 = true;
    updateEntirePage("formShowField1");
}

public void shown2(){
    showfield1 = false;
    updateEntirePage("formShowField1");

    showfield2 = true;
    updateEntirePage("formShowField2");        
}
```

Comment: The tutorial (it is effectively not a 'tutorial', just a component showcase) and it assumes some basic jsf knowledge. Using an `h:form` instead of a plain form being one of them. And please try running in jsf development mode while developing. High change you'll get a warning then

Comment: .. and check the PDF documentation instead of the showcase for more detailed information.

Comment: @GabryellRodrigues I edited my answer and added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by comments, there are multiple issues with your XHTML code.

1) Use `<h:form>` instead of `<form>`

2) The p:steps component is readonly by default. Set `readonly="false"` in order to have interactive menu items. In this mode, it needs to be placed somwhere inside a `h:form` to - I get a `javax.faces.FacesException: MenuItem must be inside a form element` else.

3) Your menuItems update the `p:steps` component only. Your other panels won't ever show up this way as they are not updated. You should update an element containing them too. Don't know what `updateEntirePage` is though, especially when invoked twice.

4) Bean names like Java variables typically start with lower case character.

Try it like this:

```
<h:form>
  <p:steps id="testSteps" readonly="false">
    <p:menuitem value="Personal" update="@form" actionListener="#{beanTest.shown2()}"/>
    <p:menuitem value="Seat Selection" update="@form"/>
  </p:steps>

  <p:panel rendered="#{neanTest.showfield1}">
    <p:outputLabel value="FORM 1"/>
  </p:panel>

  <p:panel rendered="#{beanTest.showfield2}">
    <p:outputLabel value="FORM 2" />
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

And in your bean:

```
public void shown2(){
    showfield1 = false;
    showfield2 = true;
}
```

Comment: Then you have nested forms which is not allowed.

Comment: @Kukeltje when replacing `form` with `h:form` and nesting `p:steps` in a `h:form` in OPs provided source code there wouldn't be nested forms. Nevertheless the answer is incomplete and I'll edit.

Comment: You are right, sorry, thought the others were inside steps... Good improvement btw. !